# How to check if value exist in list with line separated inside elements

Tags: python, list

I need to check if value (for example `13` or `17.5`) exist in ranges defined in a list of strings such as:

```
L = ["12-14", "15-16", "17-20"]
```

For example, the ranges would be `12` to `14` inclusive, `15` to `16`, etc.

I would like:

```
if "13.5" in L:
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

Expected output: `yes`

How can I do this?

Comment: So...you want Python to give you the wrong answer?

Comment: I think they may be ranges.

Comment: Your items are strings and Python won't understand them as ranges.

Comment: @wim No, I want expected output: yes...

Comment: I dont understand the downvotes on this. It seems to be a valid question

Comment: Related:  [Python representation for a set of non-overlapping integer ranges \[closed\]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50592912/674039)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the items in the list represent ranges, you could try something like this:

```
def check(x, ranges_list):
    x = float(x)
    for s in ranges_list:
        start, end = s.split('-')
        if float(start) <= x <= float(end):
            return True

    return False

my_ranges = ["12-14", "15-16", "17-20"]
if check('13.5', my_ranges):
    print('yes')
else:
    print('no')
```

Obs: this assumes that all numbers can be converted to `float`.

Answer (score 6):

Using `.split()` and then comparing against items in the list using `any`

```
lst = ["12-14", "15-16", "17-20"]

if any(int(i.split('-')[0]) < 13.5 < int(i.split('-')[1]) for i in lst):
    print('yes')
else:
    print('no')
# yes
```

Answer (score 1):

The string representation is a bit crude, how about a simple class `MyRange` where you can simply issue `x in m` for a number `x` and an instance `m` of `MyRange`?

```
>>> class MyRange:
...:    def __init__(self, start, end):
...:        self.start = start
...:        self.end = end
...:    def __contains__(self, x):
...:        return self.start <= x <= self.end
...:    def __repr__(self):
...:        return '{}({!r}, {!r})'.format(type(self).__name__, self.start, self.end)
>>> 
>>> lst = ["12-14", "15-16", "17-20"]
>>> 
>>> my_ranges = [MyRange(*map(float, s.split('-'))) for s in lst]
>>> my_ranges
>>> [MyRange(12.0, 14.0), MyRange(15.0, 16.0), MyRange(17.0, 20.0)]
>>> 
>>> any(13.5 in r for r in my_ranges)
>>> True
>>> any(11.7 in r for r in my_ranges)
>>> False
>>> any(17.5 in r for r in my_ranges)
>>> True
```

The `__contains__` check succeeds if `x` is equal to the endpoints, you can change this behavior with using `<` instead of `<=`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of tuple for easy lookup

```
L = ["12-14", "15-16", "17-20"]
L_tup=[tuple(map(int,k.split('-'))) for k in L]
num=13
for i in L_tup:
    if i[0] < num <i[1]:
        print('yes')
        break
    else:
        print('no')
```