# Do I have a trivial way to classify numbers into different ranges?

Tags: python-3.x

There is a list :

```
ranges = [(0,11), (11, 20), (20, 35), (35, 40), (40, 50), (50, 62), (62, 
75), (75, 83), (83, 90), (90, 100)]
```

For example, (7, 8) means 7<=x<8.
Now that there is a number n, I want to classify it into different ranges.

I was thinking about:

```
ranges = [(0,11), (11, 20), (20, 35), (35, 40), (40, 50), (50, 62), (62, 
75), (75, 83), (83, 90), (90, 100)]
n = 22
for pair in ranges:
   if pair[0] <= n < pair[1]:
   print(f'{n} in the range：{pair}')
```

The time complexity of this is O(n)
But if there is a list of numbers to be classified, the time complexity become O(m*n). Under this circumstances, do we have a trivial way to make the time complexity O(m)?

Any answer is appreciate.

Comment: a few options: create all keys in your ranges, that way you can find the range is constant time from a dict. sort the list so you don't have to go through all the ranges each time. Or, find the range by binary search. The first option is O(m), the other 2 are nlogn

Comment: [Interval tree](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50592912/674039) data structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I would go with [pandas.cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.cut.html) function.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=your_list, columns=["data"])
bins = np.array([0,11,20,35,40,50,62,75,83,90,100])
df["bucket"] = pd.cut(df.data, bins)
print(df.head())
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think O(m) is possible for this, but O(mlogn) is manageable by binary search(instead of linear search as you proposed), as your ranges list is "sorted"

And O(mlogn) is still scalable, because log function grows very slow for big n, and in that case, there isn't that much difference between logn and a constant.